# Can't get two divs to horizontally align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get `<head>` and `<head>` to align horizontally. I've tried using `.header_nav {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    }` but it doesn't seem to be working.

You can check the actual page at http://www.bolistylus.com

Thanks for your help!

```
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
            <div class="header_nav">
            <div class="head">
                <hgroup>
                    <h1 id="site-title"><a href="/"><img class="title-image" title="Boli Stylus" src="http://www.bolistylus.com/wp-content/uploads/boli-logoLimeBlack.png" alt="stylus for iPad"/></a></h1>
                    <h2 id="site-description"></h2>
                </hgroup>
            </div>
            <div class="head">

            <ul>

                            <li><a href="/shop">SHOP</a></li>      


                            <li><a href="/about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>


                            <li><a href="/cart">YOUR CART</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>  
</div>





    </header><!-- #branding -->
```

Here is the css for the stuff inside:

```
.header_nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
}

#branding img {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    width: 34%;
}

.header_nav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F3;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `<head>` and `<head>`?  You mean `.head` and `.head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats and clearing are a bear - here's how I get around it (this isn't the cleanest, but it works).

First, you need to use float: left; for *both* divs. Also, you can get later elements to line up better if you go:

```
<div id="header_nav">
<div class="head" style="float:left">...</div>
<div class="head" style="float:left">...</div>
<br style="clear:both"/>
</div>
```

Again, the use of a break isn't the best (there's better ways, but I can't get them to work consistently since I'm also somewhat novice), and definitely use CSS and not inline styling.

Edits: I misunderstood you wanting two "head" classes to float - changed it but was beaten to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

You want the divs inside header_nav to float, not header nav itself.

```
.header_nav .head { float: left; }
```

Then add a break with clear both afterwards

```
<header id="branding" role="banner">
        <div class="header_nav">
          <div class="head">           </div>
          <div class="head">             </div>  
          <br style="clear: both;"/>
        </div>
</header><!-- #branding -->
```

Comment: did what you said, nav bar is still under the logo.

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere. This is the same answer as the one you accepted. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the clear:both. It's what breaks the float. Clear:both means "I don't want anything to be on my left or right sides"